# Selecting Distinct Attributes From Other Distinct Attributes

Tags: mongodb

I am revisiting an old project where I first used MongoDB. In this project my model is defined as:

```
var ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  category: {type: String},
  subcategory: {type: String},
  status: {type: String},
  description: {type: String},
  value: {type: Number, default: 1}
});
```

The `Items` collection contains hundreds of documents in this format.

Now, I am trying to return a list of distinct `Category`'s with all associated distinct `Subcategory`'s nested in them. The desired output would be something like:

```
{
    "CategoryName1": [
        "SubcategoryName",
        "SubcategoryName",
        "SubcategoryName",
        ...
    ],
    "CategoryName2": [
        "SubcategoryName",
        "SubcategoryName",
        "SubcategoryName",
        ...
    ]
}
```

With the current model I have, and with each category and subcategory being listed more than once for each item, would this type of query be possible? Or would a restructuring of the data be needed? Since this was my first attempt, I am not against reformatting the data.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `$group`.

Comment: Was just reading up on this, going to test a few things then report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working by using the following:

```
db.items.aggregate(
   [
     { $group : { _id : "$category", subcategory: { $addToSet: "$subcategory" } } }
   ]
);
```